# EF Core second object reference generates circular dependency

Tags: entity-framework, dependencies, circular-dependency

Is it not possible to have a second reference to second class? FirstClass contains SecondClasses and SeocondBegin containing the begin element. With this code I get the execption in SaveChanges:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'FirstClass { 'Id': -2147482647 } [Added] <-
SecondClasses FirstClass { 'FirstClassId': -2147482647 } SecondClass { 'Id': -2147482647 } [Added] <-
SecondBegin { 'SecondBeginId': -2147482647 } FirstClass { 'Id': -2147482647 } [Added]'.'
```

I would like the have this property because the second class should be a 'linked list' and the collection SecondClasses does not containing the
The source is:

```
namespace EFTestApp
{
    public class FirstClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? SecondBeginId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(SecondBeginId))]
        public SecondClass SecondBegin { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty(nameof(EFTestApp.SecondClass.FirstClass))]
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public ICollection<SecondClass> SecondClasses { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace EFTestApp
{
    public class SecondClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int FirstClassId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(FirstClassId))]
        public FirstClass FirstClass { get; set; }
        public SecondClass Next { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace EFTestApp
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=sample;Trusted_Connection=True");
        }

        public DbSet<FirstClass> FirstClasses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SecondClass> SecondClasses { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace EFTestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var firstClass = new FirstClass()
            {
                Name = "First"
            };
            var secondClass = new SecondClass()
            {
                FirstClass = firstClass,
                Url = "Blablah"
            };
            
            firstClass.SecondBegin = secondClass;

            dbContext.Add(firstClass);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's fine to have a cycle, but you can't create it with a single call to `SaveChanges()` as EF isn't able to INSERT either row without the other.

You'll have to call SaveChanges twice here, once to insert the entities, and then again to "close" the cycle.

Eg

```
dbContext.Add(firstClass);
dbContext.Add(secondClass);
dbContext.SaveChanges();

firstClass.SecondBegin = secondClass;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: isn't this a problem only if you rely on Id's being generated by the database? We have configured our model to generate Id's in code using `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` and have configured the database to defer constraint checks. That way it should be possible to insert the two entities in the same call to SaveChanges. However, we still get this exception although I am not sure why..?

Comment: You'll get that error in EF regardless of whether it would actually fail at the database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, David! It would be nice to be able to configure EF to be lenient in these checks for when "we know what we are doing". :)  For now, though, the fix of updating the database in multiple SaveChanges works for us.